# SQL: Join and Count based on condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Items (id INT, name VARCHAR(8));
CREATE TABLE Likes (item_id INT, usr VARCHAR(8), doeslike BOOLEAN);

INSERT INTO Items VALUES 
    (1, 'Pen'),
    (2, 'Pencil'),
    (3, 'Ruler');

INSERT INTO Likes VALUES
    (1, 'joe', TRUE ),
    (1, 'jill', TRUE ),
    (1, 'jack', FALSE),
    (2, 'jae', TRUE ),
    (2, 'jill', FALSE),
    (2, 'john', FALSE),
    (2, 'jer', TRUE ),
    (3, 'mill', TRUE ),
    (3, 'mack', FALSE),
    (3, 'moe', TRUE ),
    (3, 'gill', TRUE ),
    (3, 'zack', FALSE);
```

Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d1e0f

I need a query that lists the items and number of people who like and dislike each item, like so:

```
ITEM    LIKES   DISLIKES
Pen     2       1
Pencil  2       2
Ruler   3       3
```

Comment: you have wrong value in your expected result Ruler -> Dislikes = 2 not 3

Comment: You're right, looks like I really need the SQL to do my counting for me ;)

Comment: Or you mustn't count like=false as dislike :-) if nobody upvoted, that does not mean that everybody downvoted :-) ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation for this. If you use `SUM(condition)` inside of a select statement, you'll get the number of times that condition is true. Use it like this for your table:

```
SELECT i.name, SUM(l.doeslike = true) AS likes, SUM(l.doeslike = false) AS dislikes
FROM items i
JOIN likes l ON l.item_id = i.id
GROUP BY i.id;
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d1e0f/27) example. I would also recommend using a LEFT JOIN if there is a chance an item exists without having any likes/dislikes.

Answer (score 4):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d1e0f/2

```
SELECT Items.* , 
SUM(CASE WHEN Likes.doesLike THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as likes,
SUM(CASE WHEN Likes.doesLike THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as dislikes

FROM Items
LEFT JOIN Likes
ON
 Items.id = Likes.item_id
GROUP BY Items.id
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
SELECT 
I.name AS 'ITEM'
,SUM(CASE WHEN L.doeslike = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'LIKES'
,SUM(CASE WHEN L.doeslike = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'DISLIKES'
FROM ITEMS I
INNER JOIN LIKES L
ON I.ID = L.ITEM_ID
GROUP BY I.id
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this might serve your needs:

```
SELECT count('Likes.usr') as Likes, Items.name AS Product FROM Likes LEFT OUTER JOIN Items ON Items.id = Likes.item_id GROUP BY Product
```

best regards.

Answer (score 0):

> Use LEFTJOIN to Join the tables and then count the Boolean field to
>   get the Likes and dislikes

```
select a.name as ITEM,SUM(CASE WHEN b.doesLike THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as LIKES ,
SUM(CASE WHEN b.doesLike THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as DISLIKES from Item a left join Likes  b  a.id = b.item_id
GROUP BY a.id
```